# Elmah and DbEntityValidationException

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, elmah

I have setup a project with both Elmah and EF4.1 Code First.

The project is throwing a `System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException`, but Elmah is not providing enough detail to determine what validation is failing. All that is logged is:

```
System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
```

Is there a way to make Elmah expand and log the `EntityValidationErrors` property?

Comment: it would be better if you handle this error and highlight the error in the UI/show a message without crashing and logging this error.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<IUserFeedback> errors = new List<IUserFeedback>();

try
{
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    Updated(this, HasUnsavedChanges);
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    foreach (var x in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        foreach (var y in x.ValidationErrors)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y.PropertyName))
                errors.Add(new UserFeedback() {
                    FeedbackFlags = TypeOfUserFeedbackFlags.Error,
                    Message = String.Format("Unable to save {0} due to an issue with its \"{1}\" value. The error returned was \"{2}\"",x.Entry.Entity, y.PropertyName, y.ErrorMessage)
                });
            else
                errors.Add(new UserFeedback() {
                    FeedbackFlags = TypeOfUserFeedbackFlags.Error,
                    Message = String.Format("Unable to save {0} due to the error \"{1}\"", x.Entry, y.ErrorMessage)
                });
        }
    }
}

return errors;
```

Comment: This is nice but as I understood, it was always best to not have exception code where possible and I think here we can use something like IEnumerable<DbEntityValidationResult> validationResults = this.GetValidationErrors(); BEFORE calling `SaveChanges()`?